# How to convert a decimal number into symbolic representation?

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers

With sympy, I am aware you can you do something like this:

```
In [37]: sqrt(8) / sqrt(27)
Out[37]: 2*sqrt(6)/9

In [38]: pprint(sqrt(8) / sqrt(27))
2⋅√6
────
 9
```

There is a complex number I would like to represent in the same "symbolic" manner:

```
In [39]: z = complex(1,2)
```

The length:

```
In [42]: Abs(z)
Out[42]: 1.73205080756888
```

Now I would like to represent that number as :

```
In [46]: pprint(sqrt(3))
√3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `complex` type as that can only represent complex numbers using floating point. Instead use SymPy's `I`:

```
In [1]: from sympy import I

In [2]: z = 1 + 2*I

In [3]: z
Out[3]: 1 + 2⋅ⅈ

In [4]: abs(z)
Out[4]: √5
```

Also worth noting that sometimes SymPy can convert a float back into a guessed symbolic form:

```
In [5]: e = abs(complex(1, 2))

In [6]: e
Out[6]: 2.23606797749979

In [7]: from sympy import nsimplify

In [8]: nsimplify(e)
Out[8]: √5
```

Comment: Hi thank you , it is doing what I asked - but the value(magnitude) being returned is incorrect. `z = complex(1,2); Abs(z) = sqrt(3)`
Whilst this method using the ImaginaryUnit is returning `sqrt(5)`

Comment: The value is being returned is *not* incorrect.